# How can I pass enum objects as a dictionary key in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary, enums, key

I have two simple enums like:

```
enum A: String {
    case i = "i"
    case j = "j"
}

enum B: String {
    case x = "x"
    case y = "y"
    case i = "i"
}
```

And, I have a dictionary which maps all enum values with some other values.

```
var myDict:[String:String] = [
    A.i.rawValue : "i in A",
    A.j.rawValue : "j in A",
    B.x.rawValue : "x in B",
    B.y.rawValue : "y in B",
    B.i.rawValue : "i in B"
]
```

Running this code throws an error:

> Fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys

Because a dictionary can not hold same multiple keys in it.

**Question:**

Is it possible to pass enum objects instead of their raw values? Something like this:

```
var myDict:[<Dont know what to type here>:String] = [
    A.i: "i in A",
    A.j: "j in A",
    B.x: "x in B",
    B.y: "y in B",
    B.i: "i in B"
]
```

Help needed!

Comment: What are you trying to do by putting them into a dictionary? There's no difference in `A.i.rawValue` and `B.i.rawValue`. Both work out to the string `i`.

Comment: For only demonstrate my problem, I used simple enums. The actual part does not simply returns strings. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the key to be of type `AnyHashable`.

```
var myDict:[AnyHashable: String] = [
    A.i: "i in A",
    A.j: "j in A",
    B.x: "x in B",
    B.y: "y in B",
    B.i: "i in B"
]

print(myDict[A.i] ?? "") // "i in A"
print(myDict[B.i] ?? "") // "i in B"
```

The basic requirement for a dictionary key is that it conforms the protocol `Hashable`, and `enum` conforms to it.